# image stretch with 100% width and 300px in height

Tags: html, css

i have a page with slider and my slider is a 100% in width and 300px in height, but when i try to put some image in my slider all of the image are stretch.i tried several methods but its seems its not working with mine..can someone please help me fix this..

**code for slider**

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Image/car1.png" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Image/car2.png" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
     object-fit: cover;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... width: 100% is using the width of your parent. So if you're parent is 1000px and your image is 300px, it's going to stretch to your parent if you're using width: 100% unless you set a defined width.

Comment: i set my image in photoshop by 1000px width and 300px in height, and in my webpage i set it 100% in width and 300px in height.

Comment: You are asking the image to stretch in your code, so what do you expect? Centering the image with a fixed width for example? Or stretching the image until a certain width only?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ what i just want to accomplish is to make the image 100% width of the window and just the height of 300px..is that possible?or if not what should do to make make it 100% in width?